# php Get data from url

Tags: php

I have a system where in users can create forms dynamically.  Once the form is created a unique URL is generated and stored in the database . These URL's are for calling the form back when the users type it out in the browser .

Now i want a particular file to read the url when the users type out the generated url in the browser , so that i can get the last segment of the url which is unique and fetch the respective data at run time .

I cant seem to figure out how to do that .

Comment: I'm confident someone here can help, it's just hard to understand what you're asking here.  Can you rephrase the question a little bit?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are trying to receive data from a URL string, you will need to use the `$_GET` variable .

If the url is `http://domain.com/page.php?var1=some-string`

You would retrieve `var1` like so:

```
<?php
$var1 = $_GET['var1'];

echo $var1; //would output "some-string"
?>
```

Is this what you're asking or is it something more in-depth?

Comment: yes exactly...if the url is pasted on the browser...it shud be read by a particular php file.

Comment: When the url xyz.domain.com/form/whatever is typed on the browser at anytime..i want it to be read by a php file.

Comment: Well, then this is the code you need. Just substitute out any variables in that you would like.  If this is the right answer, please mark it as such.